# Is there some way to get props in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox

Is there some way to get props in react component to manipulate with it and send to render.

For example:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class MapBox extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'here my token';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'some info', { zoomControl: false }).setView([48, 17], 5);

    new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(map);

    var path = [];

    this.props.data.map(function(item, i) {
      var icon;
      if (i === 0) {
        icon = L.mapbox.marker.icon({
          'marker-color': '#1087bf',
          'marker-size': 'large',
          'marker-symbol': 'airport',
        });
      } else {
        icon = L.mapbox.marker.icon({
          'marker-color': '#f86767',
          'marker-size': 'large',
          'marker-symbol': 'airport',
        });
      }

      var coordinates = [];
      var data = item.coordinates;

      data.map(function(item) {
        coordinates.push(parseFloat(item));
      });

      L.marker(coordinates, {
        icon: icon,
      }).addTo(map).bindPopup(item.flight.from.city);

      path.push(coordinates);
    });

    path.push(path[0]);

    var polyline_options = {
      color: '#1087bf',
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 1
    };

    L.polyline(path, polyline_options).addTo(map);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      div id="map" className="map_result"
    );
  }
}
```

Please, don't look to the render block html, because I don't know how to post it with brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to `this.props` within the `render` method. If you want to compute `path̀̀` every time your component renders then compute it there. If you want to compute only once -as it seems like- then assign it to `this.path` instead of a local variable or store it into the component's state using `this.setState({ path: path })`.

Also, when using `map` you want to return an object from the function you pass to it that you want to be stored in the resulting array:

```
var path = this.props.data.map(function(item, i) {
    // compute coordinates
    return coordinates;
});
console.log(path); // [coordinates_for_data_item_1, coordinates_for_data_item_2, coordinates_for_data_item_3]
```

Comment: Yes, but what about manipulate with data in react, when you need to create a map with props data, like in example?

Comment: Edited my answer, see the second part.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ES6, to get props object you have to define constructor to access to them:

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
  export default class MapBox extends Component {

    // Add this block to your code 
    constructor(props) { // <<------ see them
      super(props);
      this.props = props;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      L.mapbox.accessToken = 'here my token';
      var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'some info', { zoomControl: false }).setView([48, 17], 5);

      new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(map);

      var path = [];

      this.props.data.map(function(item, i) {
        var icon;
        if (i === 0) {
          icon = L.mapbox.marker.icon({
            'marker-color': '#1087bf',
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'airport',
          });
        } else {
          icon = L.mapbox.marker.icon({
            'marker-color': '#f86767',
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'airport',
          });
        }

        var coordinates = [];
        var data = item.coordinates;

        data.map(function(item) {
          coordinates.push(parseFloat(item));
        });

        L.marker(coordinates, {
          icon: icon,
        }).addTo(map).bindPopup(item.flight.from.city);

        path.push(coordinates);
      });

      path.push(path[0]);

      var polyline_options = {
        color: '#1087bf',
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1
      };

      L.polyline(path, polyline_options).addTo(map);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        div id="map" className="map_result"
      );
    }
  }
```